# What is a suitable sanitize_callback for logo image in Customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer

My code is like that

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'scroll_logo',
    array(
        'default'           => '',
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr',
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'scroll_logo', array(
    'section'       => 'title_tagline',
    'label'         => __( 'Upload Scroll Logo', 'bar-restaurant' ),
    'description'   => __( 'Logo Size (120 * 60)', 'bar-restaurant' ),
    'flex_width'    => true,
    'flex_height'   => true,
    'width'         => 120,
    'height'        => 50,
    'priority'      => 19,
    'default-image' => '',
) ) );
```

Comment: what is actually the quesion? why do you need to sanitize at all?

Comment: It's a great question, because sanitizing image files is often ignored, but all settings in the Customizer should be sanitized per best practices.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to sanitize values being accepted from the user. A `WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control` will populate its associated setting with an attachment ID. Thus you could use `absint` as the sanitizing function.

Remember that `esc_attr` is an escaping function and should only be used when printing out a value to the page, and here particularly in an HTML attribute. Note also that `esc_url_raw()` is not an escaping function, despite its name, but rather is actually a sanitizing function.

Comment: This. Also, I linked to you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841114/found-a-customizer-setting-that-did-not-have-a-sanitization-callback-function-w

Answer (score 1):

A good image file sanitizer example:

```
function ic_sanitize_image( $file, $setting ) {

    $mimes = array(
        'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif'          => 'image/gif',
        'png'          => 'image/png',
        'bmp'          => 'image/bmp',
        'tif|tiff'     => 'image/tiff',
        'ico'          => 'image/x-icon'
    );

    //check file type from file name
    $file_ext = wp_check_filetype( $file, $mimes );

    //if file has a valid mime type return it, otherwise return default
    return ( $file_ext['ext'] ? $file : $setting->default );
}
```

How to implement it:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'logo', array(
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'default'           => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'ic_sanitize_image',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'logo',
    array(
        'label'    => __( 'Logo', 'text-domain' ),
        'section'  => 'general',
        'settings' => 'logo',
    )
) );
```

Source:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_image_control/#comment-5368

More fantastic examples:

https://divpusher.com/blog/wordpress-customizer-sanitization-examples/