# How to return responsive images from a sanitize_callback?

Tags: images, theme-customizer, sanitization

I'm trying to sanitize the images of the customizer from my theme.

I found an example on [this topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282149/need-help-for-suitable-sanitize-callback-for-scroll-logo-in-customizer#new-answer?newreg=742acfddce0440f591012875170cbbc9) and it works, but makes my template stop showing the image.

With a `var_dump()`, I found out that the sanitization function returns the image url instead of the id. So, if I use `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` function in order to obtain a responsive image on my template by passing the size parameter, the image breaks.

There is a way to return the id of the image in the sanitize function so I can use `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` instead of `echo get_theme_mod()` on my template?

[Edit]

If my question was not objective enought, I want my sanitize_callback to return the image id instead of the image URL. Is that possible?

[Edit]

The code on functions.php:

```
function cs_sanitize_image( $file, $setting ) {

$mimes = array(
    'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
    'gif'          => 'image/gif',
    'png'          => 'image/png',
    'bmp'          => 'image/bmp',
    'tif|tiff'     => 'image/tiff',
    'ico'          => 'image/x-icon'
);

//check file type from file name
$file_ext = wp_check_filetype( $file, $mimes );

//if file has a valid mime type return it, otherwise return default
return ( $file_ext['ext'] ? $file : $setting->default );
}
```

The code on customizer.php

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'logofund1', array(
    'default'           => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'cs_sanitize_image',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'logofund1',
    array(
        'label'    => __( 'Logo', 'text-domain' ),
        'section'  => 'general-fund-i',
        'settings' => 'logofund1',
    )
) );
```

The code on template-my-page.php

```
<?php $logo = get_theme_mod('logofund1');  if ($logo) : var_dump($logo);?>
<img alt="Image" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($logo, 'full'); ?>" style="width: 100%;">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you share the full relevant code. I’m not sure why you’d be using `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` to sanitise a value?

Comment: I'm using wp_get_attachment_image_url() on  theme page tempate to show the image that was uploaded via customizer. I will edit the post with the code.